# php pass class to function

Tags: php, function, class

I have a class with property transof

```
    class translator {
      public function transof($phrase) { gives translation of phrase }
    }
```

Now I want to pass an instance of translator to a function:

```
    function parse($part,$class) {
       $class->transof($part);
    }

    $tr = new translator("project","en");
    parse("exception",$tr);
```

Do anyone know how to do this?
 I know this example is to simple, and can be easily written without the use of a function, but in my real world example I would like to be able to use a function.

Of course I can use global $tr in the function, and use it inside the function, but I don't like using global.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like you're mixing procedure programming and OOP. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Your parse function does not return any value, or do you want to print the message in the transof method of your class?

Comment: Are you getting any error in above code ?

Answer (score 0):

It does what you intend, the object is passed to the function parse. All you need to do is to include the class definition file in or before the php file which contains parse definition or get use of `__autoload()` function which will include class definition when needed.
You can also define parse this way:

```
function parse($part, translator $class) {
       $class->transof($part);
}
```

Then code editors as Aptana etc. will know what class this object is an instance of and will be able to provide you with hints concerning your class structure.

Comment: Thank, this is what I was looking for. Would vote it up, but have not enough points, or something.

Comment: @user3759722 I am glad it helped. You can however accept this answer regardless of the rep! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create object in global code to have better maintainability then you need to modify the signature of the function as follows:

```
function parse($part,$project,$lang) {
   $class = new Translator($project,$lang);
   $class->transof($part);
}
parse("exception","project","en");
```